# flutter web socket how to connect?

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

How to connect sockets in Flutter apps?

When connecting it outputs the following error:

`socket: ws://project.greatwisher.com:9006/ is not initialized!`

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error,
> java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ws, null,
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown
> protocol: ws E/flutter (22791):   at
> io.socket.client.Url.parse(Url.java:52)

I have used many dependencies in the sockets.

How sockets are working in Flutter?

Comment: can you show the code and package you have used to connect web socket? and have you try to test the web socket with postman or other tools to check whether the socket is in fact available?

Comment: You are trying to connect to a WebSocket. WebSockets are not the same as socket.io and not the same as TCP/IP sockets. You are probably mixing one with the other.